# Why storyboard or xib is not merge on gitlab when two developer are working on same project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

We are working on one project which have multiple module. So we all are separate module to develop. When we merge our code on gitlab it every time stuck on storyboard file. If it is merge by chance than that storyboard file not included on remote branch of gitlab.

Comment: It's sounds like you do not understand how to deal with merge conflicts because _When we merge our code on gitlab it every time stuck on storyboard file._   I doubt anyone on SO is going to be able to tell you how to solve a storyboard merge conflict. Tell your developers NOT to commit any changes to the storyboards that they are not responsible for.

Comment: or even better... have a storyboard for each separate module